# Pass UIElement to CommandParameter

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm using MVVM Light in my WPF application.

I created a class `RedirectToUriCommandArgument.cs`.

```
public class RedirectToUriCommandArgument : DependencyObject
{
    #region Properties

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Page), typeof(object), typeof(RedirectToUriCommandArgument), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public object Page
    {
        get => (object)GetValue(PageProperty);
        set => SetValue(PageProperty, value);
    }

    public string Uri { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Methods



    #endregion
}
```

In `.xaml` file, I used:

```
<Window x:Class="MainClient.Views.AppView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:v="clr-namespace:MainClient.Views"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MainClient.ViewModel"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:commandArgument="clr-namespace:MainClient.Models.CommandArguments"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MainClient"

        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:AppViewModel x:Name="AppContext"></vm:AppViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="32"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Frame NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" x:Name="PageFrame">
            <Frame.Content>
                <Page Name="MainPage"></Page>
            </Frame.Content>
        </Frame>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button>
                <Button.Content>
                    <TextBlock>Redirect to main view</TextBlock>
                </Button.Content>

                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RedirectToViewRelayCommand}">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                <commandArgument:RedirectToUriCommandArgument Page="{Binding ElementName=PageFrame}" Uri="MainView.xaml"></commandArgument:RedirectToUriCommandArgument>
                            </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                        </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The `Page` property is always null.

Am I missing anything ?

Comment: Any binding error?

Comment: No, but the property is null :(

Comment: @Redplane look in the output window for any `System.Windows.Data Error:` errors. Sadly, binding errors don't throw an exception by default...

Comment: BindingExpression:Path=Name; DataItem=null; target element is 'RedirectToUriCommandArgument' (HashCode=20031746); target property is 'Uri' (type 'String')

Comment: Are you running other code than you posted? You don't bind to 'Uri' anywhere. But to come back to the problem why `Page` is null: My guess is that you can't just bind from the `DependencyObject` to another element because the `DependencyObject`is neither in the Logical nor in the Visual tree.

Comment: Have you tried putting a converter for your `Page` binding? Just a simple one so it returns what you passed in and put a breakpoint inside of the `converter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think the problem is, that as binding been initialized the UIElement is not created(null). Afterwords the binding is not notified, that the object is created.

Binding to the properties is easyer the object must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or `DependencyObject` take care about dependency properties.

To solve your issue you could set a `Delay` for `Binding`, say to 1000ms, then it will work. It's doubtful whether it is a right way.

```
<commandArgument:RedirectToUriCommandArgument Page="{Binding ElementName=PageFrame, Delay=1000}" Uri="MainView.xaml"></commandArgument:RedirectToUriCommandArgument>
```

The right way would be just set binding's source to the UIElement:

```
<commandArgument:RedirectToUriCommandArgument Page="{Binding Source={x:reference PageFrame}}" Uri="MainView.xaml"></commandArgument:RedirectToUriCommandArgument>
```