# How to capture instantiation of DataTemplate in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a search window, which looks like following:

[image: Search window]

The part with Condition and Options is a `ContentControl` with several `DataTemplate`s, which contain different filter form for specific field (eg. datetime picker etc.).

**I'd like specific control in the `DataTemplate` to be focused after opening the window** (this is the X problem if someone asked)

I'm doing that in the following way:

```
    public FindWindow(FindModel model)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.viewModel = Dependencies.Container.Instance.Resolve<FindWindowViewModel>(new ParameterOverride("access", this), new ParameterOverride("model", model));
        DataContext = viewModel;
        FocusInput();
    }
```

FocusInput does the following:

```
    public static FrameworkElement GetControlByName(DependencyObject parent, string name)
    {
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i) as FrameworkElement;
            if (child != null)
            {
                if (child.Name == name)
                {
                    return child;
                }
                var descendantFromName = GetControlByName(child, name);
                if (descendantFromName != null)
                {
                    return descendantFromName;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void FocusInput()
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, new Action(() =>
        {
            var obj = GetControlByName(filterContainer, "input");
            if (obj != null && obj is Control ctl)
                ctl.Focus();
        }));            
    }
```

When it runs in the ctor, `FindWindow` gets null obj (despite `ContentControl` having `Content` set). However, when you click "Test" button, which simply runs `FocusControl`, the latter in turn finds required control and focuses it.

The question is: how to capture moment, when `ContentControl` finishes instantiating `DataTemplate`, such that I can capture required control? (Problem Y)

I'll be grateful for solution to either problem X or Y (which is my attempted solution).

Comment: do `FocusInput()` in `Window.Loaded` event handler.

Comment: Can it[(Pass UIElement to CommandParameter)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51184181/7713750) be helpfully for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `FocusInput()` once the window or `ContentControl` has been loaded:

```
public FindWindow(FindModel model)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.viewModel = Dependencies.Container.Instance.Resolve<FindWindowViewModel>(new ParameterOverride("access", this), new ParameterOverride("model", model));
    DataContext = viewModel;
    Loaded += (s, e) => FocusInput();
}
```

Comment: @Spook Try my solution and place behavior inside a data template. You will capture a moment when the data template will be loaded.

Comment: @Spook: Handle the Loaded element of the root element in the DataTemplate then.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, a better solution would be behavior. It is inherited from

```
using System.Windows.Interactivity;
```

And is very similar to the previous answer, and is reusable

```
public class FocusBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
   protected override void OnAttached()
    {
       base.OnAttached();
       if(AssociatedObject!=null)
       {
        //LOADED EVENT SUBSCRIBE
        AssociatedObject.Loaded += //YOUR FOCUS METHOD;
       }
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        //LOADED EVENT UNSUBSCRIBE
        AssociatedObject.Loaded -= //YOUR FOCUS METHOD;
    }
   }
```

and then attach it to your element in XAML:

```
        <TextBox
            x:Name="MainText">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <behaviors:FocusBehavior  />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </TextBox>
```